# Using English cards in France

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm an American living in France, and I want to play Magic the Gathering. Would it be a problem if I buy English printed cards to play in FNM and official tournaments here? Should I just stick to French printed cards since English printed cards may not be allowed?

Comment: Keep in mind that OP is asking about france, where they are pretty nationalistic about their language, so it's not out of the question they dont give a shit about the CR in that regard.

Comment: @Hackworth We would not be able to answer that question though as it would depend on the local rules where they are playing and only the country was provided. So all we can do is state what the official rules are.

Comment: Je ne sais pas.

Comment: Agreed. We can say what official tournaments allow and what Friday Night Magic official guidelines allow, which is what the OP is asking. We cannot say what local store XYZ (or casual players at those stores) do because we most likely have never been there.

Comment: Legally you are able to use cards in any language anywhere, by strict rules of MTG. That doesn't mean everyone will like you having cards they cannot read and need to look up the oracle text for in their language if they don't recognize the card.

Comment: Thank you all for participating in this post! I now understand that official rules state that I can use cards of any language anywhere, from FNM to official tournaments. It would make it easier to play with French cards, not only to make things easier but to simply have fun and not having to pause the game for my opponent to understand a card in English (even though I prefer to play Magic in my native language haha). Thank you all!

Comment: @Magic101 As a casual observation from a french player, most french players will have a basic understanding of english and even if they are not good at it they will be able to read english cards. English is virtually mandatory to learn at school and most people will have the bases. Of course younger people remember better what they learnt at school :) English cards are very commonplace in France (some products are not sold in french like bundles).